# How do I figure out how to state the set of all interesting points of a sinusoidal?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Sorry I don't know exactly what to call this, but by example I'm sure you'll know what I mean. I'm looking for a process in which I can go from the zeros to that set. Any help would be greatly appreciated

The question for which this is an answer is "Find the maximum and minimum currents/voltages/etc and the times at which they occur".

For example:

```
V(t) = 5sin(t) + 12
V'(t) = 5cos(t)
0 = 5cos(t)
t = π/2, 3π/2 (within the unit circle)
V(π/2)=17, V(3π/2)=7
max at t = (2k+1)π/2  ## determine this general form for all points
min at t = 3π/2 + 2kπ
```

another example:

```
I(t) = 60cos(t) + 25
I'(t) = -60sin(t)
0 = -60sin(t)
t = 0, π
I(0)=85A, I(π)=-35A
max at t = 2π+2πk
min at t = 2π + (2k+1)π
```

an example without π in the set of t values:

```
V(t) = 170sin(120πt)
V'(t) = 20400π cos(120πt)
0 = 20400π cos(120πt)
t = 1/240, 1/80
V(1/240)=170, V(1/80)=-170
max at t = (4k+1)/240
min at t = (4k+3)/240
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Um ... the set of those $t$'s that are of the form $t = (2k+1)\pi/2$ for any integer $k$ (your first example) is just $\{(2k+1)\pi/2\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}$. Is that what you want to see? Or, if not, it would be helpful if you can copy the exact words of your problem so that we can see the "other part" that you are referring to.

Comment: @StinkingBishop well, I did know that it's the set of t values that are of that form, but given some question of which computing the set of t's is the last step, I can't seem to easily go from my solutions to the zeros to that.. so a process in which I can go from the zeros to that set what I'm looking for

Comment: Oh, the exact words, The question is:
"Find the maximum and minimum currents and the times at which they occur"
"Find the maximum and minimum voltage levels and the times at which they occur"

Comment: I think I understand. You have found one maximum (or minimum) within the period of oscillation, and now you want to see _all_ maxima (or minima) across the entire time axis.

Comment: Yeah! and how to state that in the general form using a constant multiple of the (period? period + offset?). what's the logic for writing that given the information I have before that step?

Comment: Well, if $t=t_0$ is one minimum, then all minima are at $t=t_0+kT$ where $T$ is the period. In your formulae, the curve is periodic because it has a term $\omega t$ where $\omega$ is the _angular frequency_ and you have the formula $T=\frac{2\pi}{\omega}$. Say, in the first example the curve is given as $5\sin(1\cdot t)+12$ so $\omega=1$ and $T=2\pi$ so the result (for maximum) is $\pi/2+2\pi k$. In the third example, you have $170\sin(120\pi t)$ so $\omega=120\pi$ and $T=\frac{1}{60}$ and the maxima are at $\frac{1}{240}+k\frac{1}{60}$. And so on.

Comment: like it seems like offset (ie: first point) + k period, but that doesn't work for the 2nd example...

Comment: (Putting this in the comments because I am sure this can be explained better than what I could. If nobody else chips in, I may tidy it up for an answer later on.)

Comment: Alright, cool. Thanks for your help. I think I get it now. I'll check back later and accept your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh yes, it works perfectly well for the second example. Say, maximum: it is at $0+2\pi k$. This is _exactly the same set_ as $2\pi + 2\pi k$.  Both are just _integer multiples of $2\pi$_. Both are correct answers to your problem. Nobody should downmark you if you provide one instead of the other.

Comment: Ah yes, ok. I was wondering about that 0... good to know it will be a correct answer on the test. Thanks!
I guess at k=-1 then t=0 and it still works with the process

Comment: Beware one thing. Say, $V(t)=10(\sin t)^2$. It _looks_ like the period here is $2\pi$ but the period is actually $\pi$ because $(\sin t)^2=\frac{1-\cos(2t)}{2}$ so $V(t)=5-5\cos(2t)$ and so $\omega=2$. Functions like that are harder to spot, but are probably not part of your curriculum, so you probably don't need to worry.

Comment: good to know though. I'll keep an eye out for sin^2 answers and that effect on the period

Comment: Or $\cos^2 t$ because $\cos^2 t=\frac{1+\cos(2t)}{2}$.